# I want to change the order status when the shipment is occurred in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, shipping, order-status

I want to change the order status 
(custom_status) during the shipping, how to implement this as functionality in magento 2.3

Comment: Create custom status  for example in admin. Then use plugin or event in action calls when shipping is created, and set custom status there

Comment: OK please tell me the event name how to use it @KonradSiamro